# Problem sending mail to multiplle recipientes azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, email

We have a problem with an application developed in MVC .NET. Emails are sent to multiple recipients using a SmtpClient of the System.Net.Mail class. We have migrated the server to azure as a virtual machine and the email is only sent to the first recipient on the recipient list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! We need to update server roles in the server with an IIS feature that was not installed

[IIS feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A428q.png)